# Horizontal (backward/forward) scrolling between windows by touch of fingers

Tags: c++, qt

I have 2 windows. One is a main window and second a new window. I want to go to new window from main window and vice versa by scrolling(using mouse on simulator and touch on device) and not by any pushbutton or anything else. Does anyone has any idea about this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What Qt version? I think starting from 4.7 there is support for gestures. Just detect swipe or similar then toggle the window.

Comment: and where do i get to add swipe in my code?

Comment: Take a look at: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qgesture.html or take a look in the examples folders that come with Qt.

Comment: yes i have seen this but i am not able to implement it in my code. did you come across any sample code anytime?

Answer (score 0):

in case, swipe gesture is not available to you platform you can use [this code](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2010/10/detecting-swipe-gesture-in-qt.html).

And to switch window, you can use QStackedWidget to switch window.

Answer (score 0):

i found solution to my problem.
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_create_a_Page_Control_component_in_QML